# How to find input that maximizes output of a neural network using pytorch

Tags: optimization, neural-network, pytorch

I have a pytorch network, that have been trained and weights are updated (complete training).

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, H)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1, H)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(H, 1)

    def forward(self, x, y):
        h1 = F.relu(self.fc1(x)+self.fc2(y))
        h2 = self.fc3(h1)
        return h2
```

After training, I want to maximize the output of the network with respect to input. In other words, I want to optimize the input to maximize the neural network output, without changing weights. How can I achieve that.
My trial, but it doesn't make sense:

```
in     = torch.autograd.Variable(x)
out    = Net(in)
grad   = torch.autograd.grad(out, input)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Disable gradients for the network.
2. Set your input tensor as a parameter requiring grad.
3. Initialize an optimizer wrapping the input tensor.
4. Backprop with some loss function and a goal tensor
5. ...
6. Profit!

```
import torch

f = torch.nn.Linear(10, 5)
f.requires_grad_(False)
x = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.rand(10), requires_grad=True)
optim = torch.optim.SGD([x], lr=1e-1)
mse = torch.nn.MSELoss()
y = torch.ones(5)  # the desired network response

num_steps = 5  # how many optim steps to take
for _ in range(num_steps):
   loss = mse(f(x), y)
   loss.backward()
   optim.step()
   optim.zero_grad()
```

But make sure that your goal tensor is well defined wrt. the network's monotonicity, otherwise you might end up with nans.

Comment: Why do you use MSELoss, shouldn't the loss be `-f(x)`? Since you want to maximize `f(x)`?

Comment: minimize the distance between y (your goal) and f(x) is more general -- just y to whatever your goal should be

Comment: Yes, but I don't think there is any fixed goal here, the goal is to maximize the output to make it as large as possible. So what would your `y` be? I thought one could use the loss itself as `-f(x)` to capture the intended goal.

Comment: a vector containing arbitrarily high values, ideally set to the upper boundary of the network's codomain (if it has any).

Comment: Ok, that seems a bit convoluted but I think optimizes for the same thing.

Comment: What if we are using a dataloader? How does that code look like?

Comment: `for batch in dataloader: ...` instead of `for _ in range(num_steps)`

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos Maybe it is a stupid question, but how PyTorch "knows" to optimize the loss function with respect to `x`. Is it a like a new computational graph with `x` added, where now the weights are "frozen"?

Comment: think of f as a function from some weights and an input to some output, f: W x X -> Y. Normally you optimize the weights W, using various inputs X. Now you do the converse, fixing W and optimizing for X.